# Whats the difference between UNION and CROSS JOIN?

Tags: sql-server, join, union

I have been reading about this two possibilities but I'm not sure if I understood them properly.
So `UNION` makes new rows with the union of the two queries data:

```
Table1     Table2
------     ------
  1           3
  2           4

SELECT * FROM TABLE1
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLE2

Column1 
---------
   1        
   2
   3
   4
...
```

And `CROSS JOIN` makes Cartesian product of both tables:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 
CROSS JOIN TABLE 2

Column1 | Column2
-----------------
   1    |    3
   2    |    3     
   1    |    4 
   2    |    4
```

Its that ok?

Thanks for all.

Comment: You appear to understand quite well. Just be aware that UNION ALL does what you describe. UNION  goes a step further to eradicate any duplicate rows.

Comment: your query output explains the difference quite well !

Comment: Yes, that's the main difference.  You can think of it like this: `union` will stack the records from both tables one on top of the others, while `cross join` will stack them side by side, while pairing each row from the first table to each row of the second table.

Comment: Thanks for answering that quickly

Comment: UNION takes more work on the server as it has to deduce the duplicates prior to removing them before forming a resultset.

Comment: Thats actually pretty helpful because im working with 2 tables with more than 7K rows. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: I had a similar question and this thread answers most of it for me, but just want to confirm I understand.

Would it be fair to say that UNION/UNION ALL is like concatenation on axis=0 (pd.concat(axis=0)) in python and CROSS JOIN is like an outer merge in python (pd.merge(x,y how='outer')?

Would appreciate any clarification.

Answer (score 5):

The UNION operator is used to combine the result-set of two or more SELECT statements.

The JOIN keyword is used in an SQL statement to query data from two or more tables, based on a relationship between certain columns in these tables.

If there is no relationship between the tables then it leads to cross join.

Answer (score 4):

Others have already answered this question, but I just wanted to highlight that your example of the [CROSS JOIN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690(v=sql.105).aspx) should return 4 and not 2 records.

Cross joins return every combination of records from the left of the join against the right.

**Example Data**

```
/* Table variables are a great way of sharing 
 * test data.
 */
DECLARE @T1 TABLE
    (
        Column11    INT
    )
;

DECLARE @T2 TABLE
    (
        Column21    INT
    )
;

INSERT INTO @T1
    (
        Column11
    )
VALUES
    (1),
    (2)
;

INSERT INTO @T2
    (
        Column21
    )
VALUES
    (3),
    (4)
;
```

**UNION Query**

```
/* UNION appends one recordset to the end of another,
 * and then deduplicates the result.
 */
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        @T1

UNION 

    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM
        @T2
;
```

*Returns*

```
Column11
1
2
3
4
```

**CROSS JOIN Query**

```
/* CROSS JOIN returns every combination of table 1
 * and table 2.
 * The second recordset is appended to the right of the first.
 */
SELECT
    *
FROM
    @T1
        CROSS JOIN @T2
;
```

*Returns*

```
Column11    Column21
1           3
2           3
1           4
2           4
```

Also important to note that Union will need exact same number of columns for both table while cross will not.

Comment: Thanks for the examples and the clarification.

Comment: You're welcome.  I really like @NewUser's answer, which is why I upvoted it.  Great explanation of both operations.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth mentioning that unlike joins, UNION and CROSS-JOIN return all information about two tables and do not eliminate anything. But joins, inner and left/right joins, eliminate some part of the data which is not shared.